# The npx-create-react-app doesn't work on my laptop

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with creating a react application. I used the command npx-create-react-app from the official react doc, but it doesn't work. I use the nodeJS terminal and the command works for a moment
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
After these messages appear, the npx command stops and nothing else appears on the terminal. I know that a React app requires some time, but it's still the same in my pc. When I ran the command on another pc, it worked just fine. I tried every other command but to no avail. I wonder what it could be. Is it my pc fault. what should I do?

Comment: Without proper error message I don't think anyone can help you but you can try and use vite. `npm init vite`. It's a little different than CRA but will do the work.

Comment: Some developers suggest to use vite instead of create-react-app. Because the create-react-app has bad features like downloading last version of the packages. My suggestion is you should research the differents between packages.

Comment: Could you plz share the package.json and error code of your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall and clear your cache.

```
$ npm uninstall -g create-react-app
$ npx clear-npx-cache
```

Then try it. Hope it would work.

```
npx create-react-app my-app     
cd my-app      
npm start
```

Comment: thank you. all i needed to do was formatting my laptop and now it's working perfectly fine